# How did they get the entrapped testicles shot in Something About Mary?

Tags: effects, theres-something-about-mary

In the 1998 comedy "[There's Something About Mary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_Something_About_Mary)" there is a scene in which the prom date gets his testicles entrapped in his zipper and this mess is briefly shown as an inserted still frame. How did they get that shot? Did they zip up a stunt man's balls or something?

Comment: Probably made fake balls, why would they cause any pain on purpose to the stuntman?

Answer (score 2):

It's a rubber prosthetic. Another one in the movie was the droopy old female torso prosthetic that Kevin Dillon sees through the binoculars (when he's being a "peeping Tom" and spying through a window at Mary). Those are just like makeup effects that are common in zombie movies and *The Walking Dead* TV series.